# Summation Of Binomial & Factorial Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-theorem

Looking for an explicit formula for the following:

$$
S = \sum _{i=j}^n \frac{\binom{i}{j}}{(i+1)!}
$$

any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{i=j}^{n}\frac{\binom{i}{j}}{(i+1)!}=\frac{1}{j!}\sum_{i=j}^{n}\frac{1}{(i+1)(i-j)!}=\frac{1}{j!}\sum_{h=0}^{n-j}\frac{1}{(h+j+1)h!}$$
is just a partial sum for a hypergeometric function, but a nice upper bound exists:
$$\sum_{i=j}^{n}\frac{\binom{i}{j}}{(i+1)!}\leq \frac{1}{j!}\int_{0}^{1}x^j e^x\,dx=e\left(\frac{1}{j!}-\frac{1}{(j-1)!}+\ldots\pm\frac{1}{0!}\right)-(-1)^j. $$

Answer (score 0):

I can't give a solution to it but my hint would be that $i$ pick $j$ is equal to $\frac{i!}{(i-j)!j!}$ which combined with what you had gives
$$s=\sum_{i=j}^n \frac{1}{i(i-j)!j!}$$
Just some to think about.

Comment: The factor of $i$ in the denominator should be $i+1$.

Comment: i've tried that. is there a closed form solution to it at all?!!

Comment: @user3127040: I’d be a bit surprised. If $j=0$, you’re looking at $\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{(k+1)!}$, and if not, what you’re looking at is even messier.

Comment: Brian, you're right, my bad

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$\begin{align}S &= \sum _{i=j}^n \frac{\binom{i}{j}}{(i+1)!}\\
&=\sum_{i=j}^n \frac{1}{(i+1)(i-j)!j!}\\
&=\frac{1}{j!}\sum_{k=0}^{n-j}\frac{1}{(k+j+1)k!}\end{align}$$

This does not have a closed form but with $n\to\infty$ the sum is a $j^{th}$ anti derivative of the exponential...